# jquery-ui isn't loading ui images properly in grails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails

Having some trouble with the images that come with jquery-ui, which show up as 404-not found in the chrome inspector.

[image]

However, these files are actually in the right plact assets/images directory of my application:

[image]

The network table on the inspector, though seems to indicate some problem regarding the file type:

[image]

It looks like jquery is trying to load these pngs as text.  Could that be why there is a problem locating the file

anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVargas asked a good question which is where are other assets being loaded form in the page.  Interestly, my javascripts, which live in the grails-app/assets/stylesheet directory are being loaded as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false"></script>
```

Notice no reference to the 'stylesheet' subdirectory.  So apparently grails is somehow resolving all assets as if they all lived in the assets directory not the individual subfolder javascripts/images/stylesheets.    Apparently jquery-ui doesn't know this so it looks for image assets in assets/images/ subdirectory.

In order to get jquery-ui working properly I had to create an images directory under assets/javascripts e.g. assets/javascripts/images and put the jquery image assets in there for the app to be able to find them using the assets/images url.

Answer (score 0):

In your console screenshot, images points to `localhost:8080` and not to `localhost:8080/myapp/`. I think that's the problem.

You need to change jQuery UI paths to use your application correct path or as workaround in Config.groovy, add this line:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```

Comment: Using Grails 3, no config.groovy.  Does this still apply?

Comment: Also, doesn't seem like this likely the problem.  controllers load fine using localhost:8080/[controllername] with no apparent need for the appname.  jquery itself is loaded with this tag:  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?compile=false" ></script>

Comment: Could you provide me an example of an url of a found asset? Also, I don't think you need `compile=false`.

Comment: Good question.  My  stylesheets which are actually in assets/stylesheets directory are called into the page  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?compile=false"></script> so interestingly, grails knows somehow to ignore the subdirectory under "assets" when it tries to load an asset.

Comment: PS compile=false is added in by the application.js require directive  in grails 3.  I don't really know know what it means or whether it is worth figuring out how to change it.

Comment: Asset Pipeline Plugin adds it automatically depending on your environment, you don't need to add it by yourself. Also Assets find your file on the correct path (more in the docs). Im asking for the uri generated and loaded by your browser. Example: http://localhost:8080/myapp/assets/jquery-2.2.0.min.js